# Automatic stub generation in visual studio IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Today one of my colleague showed me this trick in visual studio.

He types `prop` and hits `tab` twice

This makes the visual studio automatically expands that to a property.

No doubt, its a very cool feature.

But what is this trick called as ?

And is there any trick the same way i can type in `method` so that the IDE generates a method stub for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Only the Main method can now be generated. Please see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat(v=vs.90).aspx) for a complete default list of code snippets. You can always [create your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) custom code snippet for method generation.

Comment: @AndreiV: So, the term to google here is "code snippets". try posting it as an answer and i ll accept that. Thanks for the term "custom code snippet."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricks you are referencing are called "code snippets" and are really useful for faster code writing. A complete list of default code snippets can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Only the main method has currently a corresponding code snippet. There is also a [tutorial for creating custom snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx).