# generate code block in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In eclipse there is option to generate block of commands when you press enter 
for example if I put the command for there is popup with for,foreach etc and when I choose
for example the command foreach it generate for me for each block with the context the im in and I can change it as I like .
Im using visual studio premium edition 2012 ,do I need to type all the block for every command ????

Comment: Are you asking if there are "snippets"?

Comment: Here: [Walkthrough: Creating a Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx)

Comment: Ctrl + K + X or Ctrl + K + S show some basic snippets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature that you are talking about is called snippets in Visual studio environment.

Eg.

If you wanna insert a property, you do something like this:

`prop` and press `tab` twice, the IDE produces something like,

```
public int MyProperty {get;set;}
```

leaving you to edit the just-created property by navigating (use `tab` key).

Something like `svm` and `tab` twice, you get a `public static void main` method snippet produced by the IDE.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {

     }
```

For a list of all already available code-snippets, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
You can also create your own custom code snippets and use as you wish. Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx)

I asked a similar question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024170/automatic-stub-generation-in-visual-studio-ide). Hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

If you type 'for' and press 'TAB' twice Visual Studio will generate the code block for you.

Answer (score 1):

In C# with Visual Studio exist the [Code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/snippet) [Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z41h7fat.aspx), that are ready-made snippets of code you can quickly insert into your code.

You can insert a code snippet at the cursor location, or insert a surround-with code snippet around the currently selected code. The Code Snippet Inserter is invoked through the Insert Code Snippet or Surround With commands on the IntelliSense menu, or by using the keyboard shortcuts **CTRL+K and then X or CTRL+K and then S respectively.**

The Code Snippet Inserter displays the code snippet name for all available code snippets, also includes an input dialog box where you can type the name of the code snippet, or part of the code snippet name. It highlights the closest match to a code snippet name.

**Pressing TAB at any time will dismiss the Code Snippet Inserter and insert the currently selected code snippet. Typing ESC or clicking the mouse in the Code Editor will dismiss the Code Snippet Inserter without inserting a code snippet.**

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE), open
   the file that you want to edit.
2. In the Code Editor, put the cursor where you want to insert the code
   snippet.
3. Launch the Insert Code Snippet menu in one of three ways:
4. Press `CTRL+K`, `CTRL+X`.
5. On the Edit menu, point to IntelliSense, and then click Insert
   Snippet.
6. Right-click the mouse and then select the Insert Snippet command on
   the shortcut menu.
7. Select the code snippet from the code snippet inserter and then
   press `TAB` or `ENTER`.
8. Alternatively, you can type the name of the code snippet, and then
   press `TAB` or `ENTER`.